# Need to find Time and Space complexity of my algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, time-complexity, tree-traversal

Somehow i have managed to write an algorithm for Constructing a binary tree from it's inorder and preorder traversal data.

I am not sure **how to compute time and space complexity** of this algorithm.

My guess is

```
first pass  --> n(findInNode) + n/2 (constructTree) + n/2 (constructTree)
second pass --> n/2(findInNode) + n/4 (constructTree) + n/4 (constructTree)
etc..
```

So it should be **approx(3logn)**

Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
public class ConstructTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] preOrder = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] inOrder = new int[] { 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 };

        int start = 0;
        int end = inOrder.length -1;
        Node root =constructTree(preOrder, inOrder, start, end);

        System.out.println("In order Tree"); root.inOrder(root);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Pre order Tree"); root.preOrder(root);
        System.out.println("");

    }

    public static int preInd = 0;
    public static Node constructTree(int[] pre, int[] in, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        int nodeVal = pre[preInd++];
        Node node = new Node(nodeVal);
        if (start != end) {
            int ind = findInNode(nodeVal, in, start, end);
            node.left = constructTree(pre, in, start, ind-1);
            node.right = constructTree(pre, in, ind+1, end);
        }
        return node;
    }

    public static int findInNode(int nodeVal, int[] in, int start, int end) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if(in[i] == nodeVal)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: How can this be sublinear if you insert all elements in the tree ??? At least O(N), with closed eyes.

Answer (score 1):

To estimate the runtime complexity, let’s start off with the easy one, `findInNode`:

> *T*<sub>findInNode</sub> = Ο(*n*)

Estimating `constructTree` is a little more difficult since we have recursive calls. But we can use this pattern to split the … into local and recursive costs:

With each call of `constructTree` we have local costs of *T*<sub>findInNode</sub> = Ο(*n*) and two recursive calls of `constructTree` with *n*-1 instead of *n*. So

> *T*‍<sub>constructTree</sub>(*n*) = *T*<sub>findInNode</sub>(*n*) + 2 · *T*<sub>constructTree</sub>(*n*-1))

Since the number of recursive calls of `constructTree` is doubled with every call of `constructTree`, the recursive call tree grows with each recursion step as follows:

```
                  n                    | 2^0·n = 1·n
         _________|_________           |
        |                   |          |
       n-1                 n-1         | 2^1·n = 2·n
    ____|____           ____|____      |
   |         |         |         |     |
  n-2       n-2       n-2       n-2    | 2^2·n = 4·n
  / \       / \       / \       / \    |
n-3 n-3   n-3 n-3   n-3 n-3   n-3 n-3  | 2^3·n = 8·n
```

So the total number of calls of `constructTree` after the initial call of `constructTree` is *n*, after the first step of recursive calls it is *n*+2·*n* calls, after the second step it is *n*+2·*n*+4·*n*, and so on. And since the total depth of this recursive calls tree is *n* (with each recursion *n* is decremented by 1), the number of total calls of `constructTree` sums up to:

> 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + … + 2<sup>*n*</sup> = 2<sup>n+1</sup>-1

Thus:

> *T*‍<sub>constructTree</sub>(*n*) = (2<sup>n+1</sup>-1)·*n* ∈ Ο(2<sup>*n*</sup>).

So your algorithm has an exponential time complexity.

The space complexity is also Ο(2<sup>*n*</sup>) since you have a local space cost of 1 per recursive call of `constructTree`.

Comment: I disagree with the analysis of deriving the complexity. The 2 recursive calls are constructing the binary tree, so in the end they construct n nodes. And the search takes O(n) for each node constructed. Hence the complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity = O(n^2). 2 recursive calls take O(n) to construct the binary tree with each node construction taking O(n) for a sequential search which is O(n^2).

Space complexity = constant ignoring the 2 input arrays and the constructed binary tree which is the output